# Segmentation Fault: 11 when allocating a matrix

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, segmentation-fault, exc-bad-access

I get segmentation fault when using an allocated matrix and I don't understand why. This code currently works and doesn't work dependently from the computer

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void allocMatrix(int ***M, int n, int m) {
    *M = (int**)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    int i = 0;
    while(i<n) {
        (*M)[i] = malloc(m * sizeof(int));
        i++;
    }
}


int main(void) {
    int **mat;

    int R, C;
    R = 15;
    C = 10;
    allocMatrix(&mat, R, C);
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < R; i++) {
        for( j = 0; j < C; j++) {
             *(*(mat+i)+j) = j+i*R;
        }
    }
#ifdef WIN32
    system("pause");
#endif
}
```

I get `segmentation fault: 11 or EXC BAD ACCESS` in Xcode. As said, happens only to some computers

Comment: `*M = (int**)malloc(n * sizeof(int));` obviously wrong, compare the types.

Comment: M passed as reference is a int *** and I have to get its original value. This currently works on my machine. I found out this because another PC having troubles plus my mac. What would be the right line anyway?

Comment: I think Sourav is talking about `sizeof(int)` versus `sizeof(int *)` in that line.

Comment: I'm wondering why many beginners shy away from using the possibility to return values from their functions ...

Comment: sizeof(int *) doesn't work either.

Comment: But returning the matrix directly from the function currently works (so declaring it in the function)

Comment: Change `*(*(mat+i)+j) = j+i*R` to `mat[i][j] = j+i*R`  More readable, and more likely to work.

Comment: On what line does xcode say the segmentation fault occurs?

Comment: *M = (int**)malloc(n * sizeof(int));

Comment: @BlackBox That line does no occur in the code you've posted.

Comment: `*M = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));`

Comment: @BlackBox: Neither does *that* line. Also, it's *extremely* for the crash to occur on that line.

Comment: @BlackBox have you checked that none of your `malloc`s return `NULL`?

Comment: Are you *sure* you changed `*M = (int**)malloc(n * sizeof(int))` to `*M = (int**)malloc(n * sizeof(int *))` as Sourav Ghosh originally suggested?  When I run your original code under Xcode I get a segmentation fault (signal 11) just like you did, and when I fix that bug the crash goes away.

Comment: My final comment is in the answer below. Thanks to everybody for your time guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof(int)` is not guaranteed to be equal to `sizeof(int*)`, so your allocated memory block is very likely to be too small. Writing to unallocated memory is undefined behaviour, sometimes it may work as expected, sometimes not.

Comment: he said that doesn't work in the comments, but I completely agree. On my 64-bit Mac sizeof pointers are 8 and sizeof ints are 4

Comment: @yano "it doesn't work" is not a useful problem description

Comment: I don't know exactly what I was doing wrong earlier not to make work that either, but now is going perfect. I realized the mistake. Unfortunately I was also issued by some recommendation of passing the matrix as return type and not as parameter. Even being (maybe) a better programming style for this job, that wasn't helping me to resolve this problem. Ty and cheers!

Comment: @M.M I agree... I assumed he meant he was still getting the seg fault with the `sizeof int` to `sizeof int*` change. No matter now, he only thought he was.